# Alternative to DNS for internal servers

Tags: dns, hosts, udp

I am setting up my first network at work.  All the servers are running CentOS 6.3 and have statically assigned IP addresses.

For example:

```
server1 192.168.0.101
server2 192.168.0.102
```

I want to be able to type something at the command line like

```
$> ssh myuser@server1
```

The quickest solution is to edit the hosts file and after some research the preferred way seems to be running a DNS server.

I think both solutions mean that I have to manually edit files but I would like my internal servers to auto-discover over UDP.
I could write something that runs a UDP service and updates the hosts file with new servers as they come online / get removed, but it seems like such a simple thing that it must exist already and I don't want to reinvent (this potentially dangerous) wheel, does anyone know of software that already does this?

Comment: Why not just running DNS, though?

Comment: Because editing files makes me sad.

Comment: DNS just requores having DHCP set up giving machines the address of your own DNS server which requires changing configurations *once* in the computer that serves DHCP leases, and also in the DNS server (once too) to assign the desired names...

Answer (score 3):

You could use ZeroConf: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS

Check avahi out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToZeroconf (ubuntu howto, should be easily adaptable to CentOS)

Comment: Please provide more details. This would be considered as 'link only answer'.